# How do you use link_with in Cocoapods to minimise the time it takes to do `pod install`?

Tags: dependency-management, cocoapods

I **just about** get what `link_with` does in Cocoapods. The documentation is very very brief about this option:

```
Specifies the target(s) in the user’s project that this Pods library should be linked in.
```

(from http://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#link_with)

The only examples assume the user isn't using target-specific pods...

```
link_with 'MyApp'
```

Ooookay then. So what is the expected behaviour of using this in a target-specific Pods library? Why is the Pods library tied to a specific target and yet has the potential to be linked to others?

e.g. what does the following mean?

```
target 'FirstTarget' do
  link_with 'SecondTarget', 'ThirdTarget'
  pod ...
end
```

I really want to know, because the way I'm currently grouping pods up at the moment makes Cocoapods `pod install` *really* slow. Just as an example, here's a bunch of common test-related pods being used in multiple targets:

```
def test_essentials
  pod 'Specta', :git => 'https://github.com/specta/specta.git', :branch => '0.3-wip'
  pod 'Expecta'
  pod 'OCHamcrest'
  pod 'OCMockito'
  pod 'OCMock'
end

target 'MyProjSpecs', :exclusive => true do
  test_essentials
  ...
end

target 'MyProjLogicSpecs', :exclusive => true do
  test_essentials
  ...
end
```

Of course my project itself has more targets — about 6 more. Using this pattern duplicates a lot of target definitions and makes it really unclear what's linked to what. In total it takes about 3 minutes in the `Generating Pods Project` and `Integrating client project` phases.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I found http://www.pqnga.com/programming/2014/05/01/cocoapods-confusing-link_with-in-multi-target-project/, which is an incredible blogpost that shows you how to use 'pseudo targets' to group your pods up. Still feeling my way around how these work in practise, especially in combination with frameworks.

Comment: I found that this method no longer works with Cocoapods 0.34.0. This is very sad, as everything takes really long to set up again.